# Git Repository not Detected in Remote VS Code Workspace

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-remote

I set up VS Code's [Remote - SSH](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh) extension to edit [ROS](http://ros.org/) projects on remote Linux machines over SSH. I'm able to view and edit code directly on the remote machines, but I'm unable to use any of VS Code's built-in git/source control functionality.

My understanding is that when I'm in a remote workspace with a .git directory, VS Code should automatically detect that the workspace is a git repository. In my case, the source control pane in the side bar does not acknowledge that I'm in an existing repo, but instead offers to initialize git. [Screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vQm38.png)

I'm definitely in a git repo, as I'm able to interact with git through VS Code's terminal just fine.

Additionally, once connected to a remote SSH workspace, if I select "clone a repository" from VS Code's welcome screen, I get the error: "It looks like git is not installed on your system."

I know that the issue is isolated to the Remote-SSH connections, as I'm able to use the built-in source control features without a problem on local projects, and I've disabled all other extensions.

Comment: And using Git outside of VS code seems to work fine over SSH?

Comment: @griffin_cosgrove Yes, these machines are headless so I've been using git over SSH without issue.

Comment: What version of Git are you running? Microsoft recommends >= 2.0.0

Comment: @griffin_cosgrove I'm running Git 2.7.4 on the machines I'm connecting to over SSH.